# How to store my dates?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, utc

I don't have much experience with Utc Dates, but from what I know, they are in most cases the best way to store dates.

But I'm currently working on a program and I'm in doubt what will be the best way to store my dates. In the program, a user can follow a course for five weeks, starting on the day of registration. Every day he has to fill in a form, which is saved for that day.

Currently, I'm saving the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of the course as `DateTime` (no Utc) Should I save this as Utc, or isn't it necessary? Because I only need the day (if the user registers on February 8th at 10:04, all the system needs to know is that February 8th is the first day of the course. Is there maybe a better way to store this information? And what would be the best way to save system-event-dates (like user logged in, account created, etc)?

I used to store the form-data also with a `DateTime`, to calculate on which day it was submitted, but I changed it so it only saves the relative day-number (e.g. day 5).

Btw, I'm using C# and a SQL Server database.

Comment: Use UTC. It's best so you know which time zone it is in (and faster)

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using?? SQL Server **2008** introduced new date-related types, like `DATETIMEOFFSET` which is a date including the timezone information for the time portion

Comment: I'm using 2008. I will look into the datetimeoffset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) has to do with the time component of a date. It's a standard way to store DateTimes so that you can compare without worrying about timezones.

If all you are worried about is the Date Component & Timezone/Location is unimportant you could just store it in the database as `2012-02-01 00:00:00`

You can get the date only component in .NET using

```
System.DateTime.Today;
```

Alternatively if you're working with some other Date...

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.Date; // <--- this will give the Date Component with the Time stripped back to 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just store the dates in a `DATE` database column, and not worry about time zones at all?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to store in UTC if there is a functional requirement for your system to be able to work with users in different timezones.

Let's say you have a user in Hong Kong and a user in Sydney looking at the same event. If you want them both see the event date (and time) in *their* timezones, then here we are, you will probably need to store it in UTC and then present to users respecting their geo locations.

If you don't have such requirements, you don't do such conversions and you only assume one timezone then you don't need to add more complexity into your system, just use Date column and store the current date there.

But if you do - go for UTC. In this scenario you will need DateTime, not just Date. This is because 21:30 in one timezone can be 2:30 *next day* in another timezone so time really matters.

When showing to a user you may convert it to the user's timezone and *then* throw time away, but in order to make the conversion correct you will need to keep time.

It is easy to work with UTC in .NET, DateTime has .ToUniversalTime() method that converts a datetime value to UTC for you:

```
var utcNow = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

there is also a property:

```
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

**EDITED**

Use TimeZoneInfo static class to convert datetimes from/to timezones you need (for example from UTC to the specified user's timezone:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(...)
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(...)
```